# ASP.net c# Check that the hours are correct

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project where I enter a date, and enter 1 or more project I want to report x-amount of hours onto.
If I say I work 9 hours per day I can put 4 hours into the first project and than 5 hours onto the other project and it will accept that and save.
But if i would put in 5 hours on the first project and 5 hours on the project it would not accept that since the amount of hours don't match up.

But one bug right now, if I only set 5 hours on project 1, project 2 will get the amount of hours I did work, in this case 9 hours.

**It will accept this since the amount of hours onto project 1 and project 2 matches up with "Tid jobbad":**
[image]

**It will not accept this because the hours doesn't match up. And if i were to post this it would give me an error message and letting me know the hours doesn't match up. And doesn't save to the database. :**
[image]

**The bug is, that it will accept this and put 5 hours onto Project 1, but project 2 will get 9 hours.:**
[image]
**And it will make the end result bad like this:**
[image]
**And this is the code:**

```
if (!numbers.Any())
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Projekt", "Inga projekt valda...");
            }
            else
            {
                int emptyHours = 0;
                foreach (string projectNumber in numbers)
                {

                    projectData.Projects.Add(new NewTimeReportModel.Project
                    {
                        Description = form["description" + projectNumber],
                        Hours = null,
                        ProjectId = Guid.Parse(form["project" + projectNumber])
                    });

                    string hourString = form["hours" + projectNumber];
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hourString))
                    {
                        emptyHours++;
                        projectData.Projects[projectData.Projects.Count - 1].Hours = projectData.Times.WorkedHours;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!projectData.Projects[projectData.Projects.Count - 1].SetHours(hourString))
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("hours_" + projectNumber, "Felaktig antal timmar");
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (emptyHours > 1 || (emptyHours == 0 && projectData.Projects.Sum(x => x.Hours) != projectData.Times.WorkedHours))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("hours_" + numbers.First(), "Antalet timmar stämmer ej överrens");
                }

                if (projectData.Projects.Any(x => x.Hours <= 0))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("hours_" + numbers.First(), "Antalet timmar måste vara större än noll");
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(form["ReportId"]))
                {
                    projectData.ReportId = Guid.Parse(form["ReportId"]);
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    projectData.SaveToDatabase(Constants.CurrentUser(User.Identity.Name));
                    ViewData["posted"] = true;

                    projectData = new NewTimeReportModel();
                }
                else if (projectData.Projects.Count == 1)
                {
                    projectData.Projects[0].Hours = null;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing this

```
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hourString))
                    {
                        emptyHours++;
                        int count = project.Count();
                        if (count > 1)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("hours_" + projectNumber, "Du måste skriva in tid på alla project.");
                        }
                        projectData.Projects[projectData.Projects.Count - 1].Hours = projectData.Times.WorkedHours;
                    }
```